# How can I define and ++ variable inside of function scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a function that return some units. For example:

```js
let id = 0;
const playerFactory = (name) => {
   id++;
   return {name, id};
}
```

Is there a way to define id and id++ it with new players creation inside of function scope?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This use case is when closures come into play. You need to make a function that returns a function; then each time the creator function is called, a new `i` with the scope you desire is created:

```js
function createPlayerFactory() {
  let i = 0;
  return (name) => {
    id++;
    return {name, id};
  }
}

const playerFactory = createPlayerFactory();

playerFactory("A"); // {name: "A", id: 0}
playerFactory("B"); // {name: "B", id: 1}
playerFactory("C"); // {name: "C", id: 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nest the function inside an IIFE.

```js
const playerFactory = function() {
  let id = 0;
  return function(name) {
    id++;
    return {
      name,
      id
    };
  }
}();

console.log(playerFactory("Fred"));
console.log(playerFactory("Joe"));
```